# Constituency tests -- is a phrase like this a constituent?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases, syntax

When we have a sentence with a strange syntactic position, how do we know if a phrase is a constituent?

For example,

> "The two shortest of the books"

Is [of the books] a constituent?

I tried the constituency tests but it passes some and doesn't pass others.

Comment: This might be a better question for linguistics or ELU,  However the quoted phrase  ""The two shortest of the books" is not a sentence, unless you mean "They are the two shortest of the books"

Comment: Yes, it's a constituent, a preposition phrase functioning as a partitive complement of the 'fused' head "shortest".

Comment: Thank you, BillJ.you answered more than one of my questions. Are you a syntactician?

Comment: 'Grammarian' would be a better description.

Comment: Thank you, anyways. I am trying to figure out if noun phrases that are introduced with determiners or Quantifiers (like some of the money) are D phrases with a Q phrase moved to the specifier place or Q phrases that take PPs complements. I got several examples from books but it is still not making sense to me. :)

Comment: In an example like "some of his remarks were offensive", "some of his remarks" is a 'fused' head NP. The fused head "some" is followed by the partitive PP complement "of his remarks". The NP "some of his remarks" is partitive in the sense that it denotes a subset of the set consisting of his remarks: we understand it to mean "some remarks form the set of his remarks". Note that "some" is a determiner (some call it a specifier). That is how these fused head NPs are analysed.

Comment: oooh, okay! interesting